# Mongoose not parsing a string to an object key

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm passing the below object to Mongoose in an ajax call:

```
{category: 'name', direction: 1}
```

I'm using Mongoose to sort the results of the query like so:

```
Site.find(query).sort(sortBy)
```

Before this call, I want to take the object from the ajax call, format it properly and insert in the query. I do so like this:

```
let sortBy = {};    
let tmp = req.query['sortBy'];
sortBy.category = tmp["category"];
sortBy.direction = tmp["direction"];
```

However, this gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

When I console out tmp, I get:

```
tmp {"category":"name","direction":1}
```

However, when I console out tmp["category"] and tmp["direction"], I get:

```
undefined undefined
```

Why can't I get it to parse the strings into object keys?

UPDATE:

The below workaround works well, but I'm still confused why the code above does not:

```
var tmp = {};
var sortBy = {};

Object.keys(req.query).map(prop => {
  if (prop === 'direction') {
    tmp[prop] = parseInt(req.query[prop]);
  } else if (prop === 'category') {
    tmp[prop] = req.query[prop]
  }
});

sortBy = {[tmp.category]: tmp.direction};
```

Why do I need this tmp object?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened to me as well. Solution is to to define the definition of fields in the schema, otherwise it will be undefined.

Comment: Do you mean to include "category" and "direction" in the Schema? I just tried to, and it resulted in the same undefined error.

Comment: I rebuilt and it's still giving me the undefined values. I'm at a loss.